# Как передать данные о нажатом пункте списка listView из первого activity во фрагменты второго activity?

Tags: java, android, listview

Помогите разобраться с такой проблемой:

Есть `BasicoActivity` со списком `listView`, который содержит названия уроков. При нажатии на элемент списка (урок) совершается переход на следующее активити `TabsActivity`, содержащее 3 таба и 3 фрагмента соответственно. Как передать данные о нажатом пункте списка из первого активити во фрагменты второго активити?

Вот код Activity:

```
public class BasicoActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

    ListView lv1;
    Cursor words;
    MyDatabase db;
    String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basico);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        db = new MyDatabase(this);
        words = db.getWords();
        startManagingCursor(words);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item_lesson,
                words,
                new String[]{"word", "trans_w"},
                new int[] {R.id.espUnit, R.id.rusUnit});
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id);


                Intent intent1 = new Intent(BasicoActivity.this, TabsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Вот код разметки элемента списка item_lesson.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/espUnit"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rusUnit"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
```

Файл разметки activity_basico.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lv1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".BasicoActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

В методе `onItemClick()` вы формируете интент, вызывающий новую активти. Для того,чтобы передать данные в эту активти их нужно добавить в этот интент:

```
@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {

  Intent intent = new Intent(BasicoActivity.this, TabsActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("pos",position); // прикрепляем к интенту передаваемые данные с ключом "pos"
  startActivity(intent);
  }
```

в принимающей активити (`TabsActivity` в вашем случае) извлекаем эти данные из интента:

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
}
```

Для передачи значения из активити в фрагмент используется похожий механизм. В активити формируем бандл и передаем его фрагменту `fragment`:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("pos", position);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

в фрагменте извлекаем полученный бандл:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
int position = bundle.getInt("pos", -1); // -1 - значение по умолчанию, если ничего не было получено.
```

Можно сократить манипуляции во второй активити, если данные требуются только в фрагменте:

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putInt("pos",getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos"));
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();` это в `onCreate`? `setArguments` подчеркивает красным: `Error:(57, 24) error: non-static method setArguments(Bundle) cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Вы можете вызывать данную конструкцию там, где требуется передать данные. Не обязательно в `onCreate()`.

Comment: Все равно та же ошибка остается.. я, наверно, делаю что-то не так. Все равно спасибо Вам.

Comment: `setArguments(bandle)` - `bandle` с маленькой буквы, в Java регистр имеет значение. Экземпляр класса, а не класс надо передавать в параметре. Если ответ вам помог, отметье его верным или проголосуйте за него.